# Bathtub faucet handle won’t turn

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub

our hot water handle barely turns on a Roman style tub deck.  With the handle on, the plastic stem driver ends up breaking after a few times turning the handle on and off.  After removing the handle we can just barely turn the valve stem with pliers…so I assume the issue is at or below there.   Picture attached.

Have seen a few tutorials on how to fix other style faucets or different issues with the faucet, but not this precise one…seemed like too small of a repair to have someone else over to do.  [image: bath tub with handle removed]

Comment: The best solution although not the cheapest is to replace the valve. If you an access panel on the other side of the wall would make it much easier.